# Div images alignment

Tags: html, alignment

When I resize my browser-window my images, which are arranged in a div, don't align well (left).

This is the URL of my website;
http://www.robinkleijnen.com/index.php

I hope anyone can help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Its the height of the 2nd image that's causing it, as its 1px smaller than the others so when they all float left the 3rd image cant go all the way over. increasing the image height to 174px like the others solves it.

Comment: Oh and if this has solved your problem can you mark mine as the answer please, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I would try removing the float on the images -- floating doesn't seem necessary here